# Setting onClickListener to editText

Tags: android, android-edittext, soft-keyboard

Hi im trying to add on click listener to editText so i can disable the softkeyboard when user clicks on edittext using this code below, how to do that?

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: `editText.setOnClickListener`... What is wrong with that?

Comment: should i declare it public?

Comment: Also, You can simply disable editing in the xml

Comment: You said you are trying to add a click listener. Where is that part of the code in your question?

Comment: i want it to editable but not with softkeyboard with my own buttons

Comment: You can `setText` on a disabled EditText

Comment: @TarekZoubi Disable editing in xml and then attach click listener like cricket said

Comment: public void hidesoftkeyboard(View v){
        _screen.setOnClickListener();
    }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First it needs to be focusable...

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:inputType="none"
    android:focusable="false"
    ... />
```

You have to implement it in your code and than just add this to get an click listener...

```
myEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // hide the keyboard
        // show own keyboard or buttons
    }
});
```

Comment: Change this in your ans above: `android:inputType="none"` and `android:focusable="true"`

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me perfectly. I tried using Text View to look like Edittext. Used a line below TextView, added as a background drawable but it was complex solution. This one is simple.

Answer (score 0):

try it and set OnClickListener

```
  <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/edt"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:editable="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and straight forward way you can set it is by editing the xml file as follows:

```
android:onClick="onClickMyEditText"
```

and define the same method in Activity class:

```
public void onClickMyEditText(View view) {
        //your code here
    }
```